# Looking for car (cigarette lighter receptacle to lightning) charger for iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, charging, car-integration

Is there any way to charge an iPhone 5 in a 2005 Cadillac (in the cigarette lighter hole)? Or am I just out of luck with an old car?

I did some searches on google but nothing came up. I also saw some car kits but I didn't understand the description when they talked about "pins". I don't see any pins on the charger that came with my new iPhone.

I went back to the Verizon store where I bought it, but they weren't any help.
I don't think Cadillac could answer my question either. After all, they are sales people not techs.
I searched on the Apple website but found nothing regarding a 2005 car.

Comment: There are plenty of charger kits which provide you with a USB port from your cigarette lighter, so you can just plug a Lightning cable in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the new Lightning connector introduced with the iPhone 5, you'll need a car charger specifically built for this connection. A quick Google search gave several hits e.g. [Amazon *iPhone 5 Car Charger - Lightning Connector*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008DNM3ZQ) or [Belkin *Car Charger with Lightning connector for iPhone 5 (10 Watt/2.1 Amp)*](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F8J075).

Nothing changed on the cigarette lighter side of things, so these chargers should work with older cars as well.

Comment: Actually you don't need a charger specifically built for the lighting connection. I had my Usb car charger well before iPhone 5s and lightning connector.  It gave enough juice to charge my 4s and or my iPad.  All I have done for my iPhone 5 is by a usb to lighting cable from apple. Which works. You just need a charger that delivers enough power and the cable. Here's a page that goes into details https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3511